# Where to put a "contact us" button in iOS game/app

Tags: mobile, ios, mobile-application, games

we have a discussion in our team. We can't decide where to put contact us button in our app. Half of us wants to put it straight into landing menu page but the other part wants to put it in the settings page.

the arguments are

1. against putting it in the menu -   it is dumb to put the least used function of the app straight into the landing page
2. against it into settings - it is unacceptable to have contact us button in settings because it’s not a setting

What do you think? Here are screens of the app.

In the settings page.

[image: Inside settings]

Vs in the menu.

[image: In the menu]

Kontakt / Kontaktujte nás means Contact / Contact us

Comment: **This is a fair question regarding information architecture.** This is a very common feature in applications, and there are certainly patterns that have emerged as a result.

Answer (score 1):

> against putting it in the menu - it is dumb to put the least used
>   function of the app straight into the landing page

You would be surprised to make the assumption that Contact Us is the least used function of the app, especially if users are having problems with it (I don't know what the app does, but if they need it and can't just simply delete it then expect them to come knocking on your door). A good rule for contact us is to think about how much time a user would want to spend to be able to contact you based on different reasons that they may have.

> against it into settings - it is unacceptable to have contact us
>   button in settings because it’s not a setting

It may not be a setting but how many other things do you have in the settings menu that is also not a setting? Usually if a user can't find something where they expect to find it, then they will look anywhere else to find it if it is important enough (refer back to the first point I made).